# Blending cylinders

Tags: modeling

So I'm trying to model two cylinders perpendicular to each other and I want them to blend into each other like this;[image: modelofthomas] but so far I haven't found a clean and reliable way to make that happen. I have tried boolean but that makes for an unclean mesh and doesn't really work. Do any of you have an idea as to what I could do? A swift answer would be well appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Its just kind of a topology thing. You have to count the verteces. Add some edge ring to the cylinder so it fit the number then delete the faces and merge the verteces. [image: Quick joining by merging verteces]